# Routing - Ng -hide , Ng-show AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-ng-repeat, angularjs-routing

I have a base HTML file dashboard. In dashboard I have included a header HTML file with a menu. .A content tml file. A footer HTML file using ng-include.
Now I want to click on the menu on the header HTML file. After the click the content HTML should hide and a new HTML page called equity should take its place. How to achieve this on clicking the menu. help me out . Am new to angularjs

Comment: You could use ngRoute.

Comment: What you want to look at is angular route, there are a ton of tutorials on it. Here's a plunker - http://plnkr.co/edit/g0tCe0McJM9BriJNK7XE?p=preview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use ngRoute to achieve this.
Instead of ng-include, use ng-view for the content.
Define initial content and equity pages separately in `$routeProvider`. On clicking the link, go to the equity page using href.

Answer (score 0):

take a look on routing and on ng-view in angularjs I am putting  a simple example here

here goes your js

```
var app = angular.module('yiiframe-routingApp', ['ngRoute']);
    app.config(['$routeProvider',
      function($routeProvider) {
        $routeProvider.
        when('/', {
          title: 'users',
          templateUrl: 'list-users.html',
          controller: 'userController'
        })
        .otherwise({
          redirectTo: '/'
        });;
    }]);

app.controller('userController', function ($scope) {
    $scope.columns = [
        {text:"ID",predicate:"id",sortable:true,dataType:"number"},
        {text:"Name",predicate:"name",sortable:true},
        {text:"Email",predicate:"email",sortable:true},
        {text:"Gender",predicate:"gender",sortable:true},
        {text:"Address",predicate:"address",reverse:true,sortable:true},
    ];
        $scope.users = [
            {ID: '1', name: 'Kuldeep Dangi', email: 'kuldeep.dangi@yiiframe.com', gender: 'Male', address: '3172/49 Faridabad'},
            {ID: '2', name: 'Aditi', email: 'aditi@yiiframe.com', gender: 'Female', address: 'Faridabad'},
            {ID: '3', name: 'Nitin', email: 'nitin@yiiframe.com', gender: 'Male', address: 'Faridabad'},
            {ID: '4', name: 'Karan', email: 'karan@yiiframe.com', gender: 'Male', address: 'Faridabad'},
            {ID: '5', name: 'Sachita Sharma', email: 'sachita@yiiframe.com', gender: 'Female', address: 'Delhi'},
            {ID: '6', name: 'Seema Pal', email: 'seema@yiiframe.com', gender: 'Female', address: 'Delhi'},
            {ID: '7', name: 'Nikhil', email: 'nikhil@yiiframe.com', gender: 'Male', address: 'Faridabad'},
            {ID: '8', name: 'Naveen', email: 'naveen@yiiframe.com', gender: 'Male', address: 'Faridabad'},
            {ID: '9', name: 'Hemraj', email: 'hemraj@yiiframe.com', gender: 'Male', address: 'Faridabad'},
            {ID: '10', name: 'Mohit', email: 'mohit@yiiframe.com', gender: 'Male', address: 'Faridabad'},
        ];
    });
```

here will go your main layoutfile

```
<div class="container">
        <div class="page-content">
            <div ng-view="" id="ng-view"></div>
        </div>
</div>
```

and here is your list-users.html

```
<table class="table table-striped">
    <tr><th ng-repeat="c in columns">{{c.text}}</th></tr>

    <tr ng-repeat="u in users | orderBy:'-id_user'" id="{{u.id_user}}">
        <td>{{u.id_user}}</td><td>{{u.name}}</td><td>{{u.email}}</td><td>{{u.gender}}</td><td>{{u.address}}</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```